# Receiving error message blocked 444

Tags: permissions

When attempting to give a user administrative permission I received this message :blocked 444. I can no longer access the site. I tried re-booting my computer - that did not work. How can I fix this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Which CMS are you using?  A screenshot might help us help you.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. It turns out that it was a problem with our IP address being blocked - we were able to unblock it once we realized that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely not linked with civicrm, but an issue with the CMS that is around it (drupal, wordpress or Joomla). You should check on the support of your CMS.